# How make TextView rounded corner borders by code in kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I created textView by code 
I want to make curved edges with borders of another color but I don't know that
this code TextView

```
val name_label1 =TextView(this)
  Layout.addView(name_label1)
  name_label1!!.layoutParams.height = 200.toInt()
  name_label1!!.layoutParams.width = 200.toInt()
  name_label1!!.x = 30.toFloat()
  name_label1!!.y = 30.toFloat()
  name_label1.text = "Hello"
  name_label1.textSize = 20.toFloat()
  name_label1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
  name_label1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
  name_label1.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD)
  name_label1.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
```

Comment: it's not smart to make it with code, all you need is xml file and one line of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Rounded Corners in Kotlin**

Define the shape (as a function):

```
@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
fun customBg() = GradientDrawable().apply {
shape = GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE
cornerRadius = 10f
setStroke(4, ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, 
R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
}
```

Use it on any TextView

```
txtView.background = customBg()
```

**Power of Extension Function:**

Extension on TextView

```
fun TextView.customBg() {
background = GradientDrawable().apply {
    shape = GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE
    cornerRadius = 40f
    setStroke(
        4, ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
    )
}
}
```

Use it as

```
txtView.customBg()
```

[image: Rounded Corners]